# Lenovo 100S-14IBR MicroSD doesn't show

Tags: 16.04, drivers, live-usb, sd-card, emmc

**EDIT 08-07-17**  I'll try to rephrase the question.  How can a device appear in a 'Live Session' and completely disappear during a normal boot?

Getting frustrated here.  Mostly seamless 16.04LTS installation, only thing that won't work is the MicroSD card reader.

The reader shows up in lspci (00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 2296 (rev 35))

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 35)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 35)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 35)
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 2296 (rev 35)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 35)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 35)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 35)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 35)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 35)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22cc (rev 35)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 35)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 35)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

The card shows up if connected by a USB card reader in three different formats, exFat, NTFS, and ext3/ext4.

The card in the internal reader worked in Windows 10 (exFat).

Now the frustrating one, the card in the internal reader shows up using the Ubuntu live USB (mmcblk2)!

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0rpmb         179:24   0     4M  0 disk 
mmcblk0boot0        179:8    0     4M  1 disk 
loop0                 7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
sda                   8:0    1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1                8:1    1   7.5G  0 part /cdrom
mmcblk2             179:32   0 118.4G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk2p1         179:33   0 118.4G  0 part /media/ubuntu/Storage
mmcblk0boot1        179:16   0     4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0             179:0    0  29.1G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p2         179:2    0   488M  0 part /media/ubuntu/c4d4b98b-eb5d-4ac5-b
├─mmcblk0p3         179:3    0  28.1G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
│ │                 253:1    0   1.9G  0 lvm  
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root 253:0    0  26.3G  0 lvm  
└─mmcblk0p1         179:1    0   512M  0 part
```

But with a normal boot, inserting the card generates no reaction whatsoever, no dmesg, no mount, no lsblk, no nuttin.

Another item of interest, in 'disks' the 32GIG eMMC built into the machine shows up as an SD card.  Is it possible Ubuntu just can't handle two SD controllers at the same time?

Your knowledge, experience, and assistance is appreciated.

**EDIT 07-28-17**
output of lspci -nnk | grep -A3 'SD Host controller'

```
00:12.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2296] (rev 35)
            Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3905]
        Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22a3] (rev 35)
```

Output of sudo dmesg | tail -n 100  (after multiple fails of paring a mouse, removing microSD, waiting, installing microSD, waiting)

```
[    4.778998] SSE version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    4.788256] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[    4.790639] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (5986:0670)
[    4.795643] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
[    4.795648] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    4.795650] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    4.795653] uvcvideo 1-5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    4.795781] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input8
[    4.803139] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[    4.803672] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.803673] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    4.809029] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    4.811105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.811380] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.905521] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    5.013428] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.043525] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.053791] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[    5.061115] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.076271] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    5.076274] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    5.143921] Adding 1939452k swap on /dev/mmcblk0p3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1939452k SSFS
[    5.419978] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.657025] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.727622] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VC: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.727626] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.727628] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.727630] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.727631] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.727634] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[    5.727636] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.757341] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[    5.771677] sdhci-pci 0000:00:12.0: SDHCI controller found [8086:2296] (rev 35)
[    5.776412] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    5.776574] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    5.776688] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    6.345200] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.892:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.345205] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.892:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.345206] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.892:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.345208] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.892:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.350204] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.900:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=742 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.350208] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.900:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=742 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.364939] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.912:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.364944] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.912:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.374553] audit: type=1400 audit(1501191741.924:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=747 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.532130] random: crng init done
[    6.597005] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.597008] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.597014] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.252743] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    7.254898] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.255160] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.460021] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.460283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.475244] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    7.596501] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   11.200899] wlp2s0: authenticate with 94:62:69:72:0b:30
[   11.219809] wlp2s0: send auth to 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (try 1/3)
[   11.221810] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   11.225750] wlp2s0: associate with 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (try 1/3)
[   11.229095] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[   11.230489] wlp2s0: associated
[   11.230563] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   12.093603] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   12.093613] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   12.093625] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   13.614497] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:8988:cb48:de88:ca3b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=879629 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[   13.614539] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:8988:cb48:de88:ca3b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=400712 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[   13.624827] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:8988:cb48:de88:ca3b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=879629 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[   13.624866] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:8988:cb48:de88:ca3b DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=400712 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[   16.160523] nf_conntrack: default automatic helper assignment has been turned off for security reasons and CT-based  firewall rule not found. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
[   25.685607] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=f0:42:1c:22:12:35:f0:03:8c:70:f8:38:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.238 DST=192.168.1.152 LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15532 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=59424 LEN=70 
[   37.668157] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=f0:42:1c:22:12:35:f0:03:8c:70:f8:38:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.238 DST=192.168.1.152 LEN=90 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=15596 PROTO=UDP SPT=137 DPT=46566 LEN=70 
[  109.854895] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[  362.065084] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[  488.016211] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[  613.968221] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[  740.228629] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[  992.131545] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1118.081673] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1244.031997] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1369.984811] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1496.241182] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1622.193221] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1625.691928] perf: interrupt took too long (2515 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
[ 1748.148543] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1850.528040] perf: interrupt took too long (3183 > 3143), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62750
[ 1873.479766] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2000.047480] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2125.997322] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2251.949080] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2377.591276] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2504.159824] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2756.060381] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 2882.013894] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 3007.964148] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 3260.172188] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 3386.123487] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 3435.812400] perf: interrupt took too long (4008 > 3978), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49750
[ 3638.026795] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:62:69:72:0b:30:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Both performed during 'normal' boot (using eMMC)

And output of sudo dmesg | tail -n 10 (after booting to USB and inserting microSD) (just to show when it does work properly - NOT during a normal boot to eMMC)

```
[  128.747616] wlp2s0: authenticate with 94:62:69:72:0b:30
[  128.755528] wlp2s0: send auth to 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (try 1/3)
[  128.757792] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  128.762276] wlp2s0: associate with 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (try 1/3)
[  128.765765] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 94:62:69:72:0b:30 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[  128.766919] wlp2s0: associated
[  128.766986] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  298.515241] mmc2: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDXC card at address 59b4
[  298.521173] mmcblk2: mmc2:59b4       118 GiB 
[  298.538077]  mmcblk2: p1
```

**EDIT 08-08-17**

Output of sudo lspci -v during live session when card is detected (only showing SD controller section)

```
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 2296 (rev 35) (prog-if 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at 91315000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

and output of sudo lspci -v on normal boot from SATA (only showing SD controller section)

```
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 2296 (rev 35) (prog-if 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3905
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
Memory at 91315000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

The difference being the flags set.  The live session boot that works has the 'bus master' and 'latency 0' flags set.  Any ideas on how to set these during a normal boot?

**Edit 08-09-17**
**An ah-ha moment might have happened**

In a normal boot that doesn't see the microSD card

```
dana@Astrolaptop3:~$ sudo modinfo sdhci_pci
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-pci.ko
```

and from a live session boot that does see the microSD card

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modinfo sdhci_pci
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-pci.ko
```

So the driver that works is part of the 4.8.0-36 kernel, the driver that doesn't work is part of the 4.10.0-30 kernel.  How do I go about using the older driver that works?  I don't necessarily want to revert the entire kernel, just the driver.

**EDIT 08-10-17**

Ubuntu bug 1710023, "4.10.0-30-generic...sdhci_pci driver does not detect microSDXC while 4.8.0-36-generic works with same hardware" added
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1710023

If this affects you, please log in to Launch pad and click the 'Does this Bug affect you.'

Comment: It can handle two or more SD controllers (and eMMC reported as a SD card is normal). Many current notebooks are just like yours (internal eMMC + microSD card reader/writer) and everything works.

Comment: There is text that shows up during boot but it goes by too fast to read it.  Is there any way to find this in a log and see if it points me in the correct direction?

Comment: The text (caught with camera) actually refers to not being able to read mmcblk0 - evidently not really a problem because that is what it eventually boots to.

Comment: I can safely rule out hardware incompatibility - it works if you boot from USB.  I can safely rule out driver incompatibility - it works if you boot from USB.  So I'm left with a setting somewhere.  If I boot from eMMC then the microSD goes dark.  Why?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 'SD Host controller'`? Also, could you please plug in a card into the (previously empty) card reader, wait ~30 seconds, then run `sudo dmesg | tail -n 100` and include the output in your question as well? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention.  Data added via edit above.

Comment: Unbrefrigginleivable!  I thought since the microSD shows up in the USB boot live installation disk, maybe it was related to the fact that the eMMC was the boot drive.  So I got a M2 SSD, installed OS on it.  Now I have a 250 gig boot drive, the 32 gig eMMC shows up, BUT STILL NO MICROSD!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Dana I tried using my SD card again after a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 (kernel 5.0.0-13-generic) and my SD card (SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)) now works properly. I have a ThinkPad E580.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to kernel 4.8.17-040817-generic fixes the issue.  Now it works.

4.8 has the 'Bus Master' and 'latency 0' flags set and I can't figure out how to set them otherwise.  4.10.x and 4.12.x were tried - both broken.

It's not a good answer, but it's an answer.  Next question is why is 4.10.xxx broken?

**EDIT 08-12-17**

Kind of expected - reverting Kernel to 4.8 broke system.  I give up.  Another in the list of things that don't work in Ubuntu.  But at least I'm getting more practice at wiping the drive and starting over.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same SD host controller (8086:2296) on an Intel NUC5CPYH using my own 4.14.69 kernel build. Apparently in that kernel (and possibly also in your Ubuntu 4.10.x kernel?) although sdhci-pci appears to be working, MMC fails to initialize unless the relevant pinctrl driver (pinctrl-cherryview in my case) is loaded first.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=803899).

Comment: Interesting and it makes sense, it's a driver issue because the hardware works.  But I have no idea how to install such driver.